# Check if the second image image exists in gallery

Tags: php, css, hover, image-gallery

I am trying to make an image hover on a list of galleries, showing the second image of each gallery if it exists.
Some galleries only have one image which is shown as a thumbnail.

The first image is $slider -> url[0] and the second one is $slider -> url[1].

Without using the if statement a problem is aroused: if the second image does not exist it shows a small error image.

I am trying to use an if statement with the required result as follows:

If the second image exists -> show the second image css style (imageexists).

Else (the second image doesn't exist-> show the alternative css style (plusbutton).

Here is the code I used:

```
<?php $imageexist=url[1]; ?>
    
<?php if(is_file(  $imageexist))           
{?> 
    <div class="image_gallery" style="hover- image: url('<?php echo $slider -> url[0];?>');">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
        <div class="imageexists"> 
           <img src="<?php echo $slider -> url[1]; ?>"
                          itemprop="thumbnailUrl"/>
    </div></a>
    
</div> 
    <?php }
else {  ?> <div class="image_gallery" style="hover- image: url('<?php echo $slider -> url[0];?>');">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
        <div class="plusButton"> 
          
    </div></a>
    
</div>
<?php }?>
```

This code does not show any error but it doesn't recognize if the image exists or not, so it shows the alternative (class plusbutton).

How could I make the code check if the second image exists or not?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check paths - this function looks where is directed. Frequently it is not desired directory, but something else.
If directory exists - no errors appears, but your images aren't there.

Check any variable right before is used, start with

```
<?php
$imageexist=url[1];
print_r($imageexist);
```

it should be an array with 'path/img_name.ext';
It produces links properly?

```
/* this is wrong */
<div class="image_gallery" style="hover- image: url('<?php echo $slider -> url[0];?>');">
```

I'm not sure what effect you wanted, but this `style` won't work;